# How to recognize on which message is this reply? Python Telegram Bot

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I am developing a telegram bot using python, and there is one thing I don't know if possible.

When someone sends in the channel a message, that is a reply to another message, and I receive it, can I see the first message, for which the reply is?

Sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's available as [`Message.reply_to_message`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message), in your case probably `update.channel_post.reply_to_message` (in case you use `python-telegram-bot`, which you tagged)